# Como permitir que só o administrador cadastre usuário com o Devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Queria saber se há como só o administrador cadastrar usuário, com o Devise. Não consigo programar isso. E aonde está o controller com os métodos do Devise, no projeto?

Comment: Boa tarde,
Já ouviu falar na gem pundit ? Estou utilizando numa aplicação com 3 níveis de acesso. Admin | Intermediario | Básico .
Ele faz toda a parte de autorização.
Basta adc no app controller e mais algumas configurações.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O Devise é uma engine. O que é uma engine? Embora se pareça muito com um plugin normal, uma engine é, na verdade, uma espécie de aplicação que você "monta" na sua aplicação.

Plugins normais apenas adicionam funcionalidades a sua app. Já engines, podem ter seus próprios controladores, modelos, views, etc. Só que isso você não consegue ver, porque fica em um namespace separado, "invisível" pra você.

Segundo a documentação do Devise, você pode sobreescrever o SessionsController do Devise da seguinte maneira:

1. Rode `rails generate devise:controllers [scope]`, onde "scope" é o nome da sua tabela de usuários (como `users`)

Agora o Devise criou pra ti um controlador em `app/controllers/[scope]/`, que herda por herança o controlador original, e permite a você sobreescrever seus métodos.

2. Configure as rotas para utilizarem esse novo controlador, e não o original:

`config/routes.rb`:

```
devise_for :users, controllers: {sessions: '[scope]/sessions'}
```

3. Se você está usando views personalizadas em `app/views/devise`, copie para `app/views/[scope]`

---

Para resolver seu problema, acho que uma `before_action` resolve:

```
class Users::SessionsController < Devise::SessionsController
  before_action :verifica_permissao, only: [...] # configure os métodos que você quer

  def verifica_permissao
    possui_permissao? || redirect_to('/')
  end

  def possui_permissao?
    # aqui você verifica se o usuário é admin
  end
end
```

### Referências:

- http://guides.rubyonrails.org/engines.html
- http://devise.plataformatec.com.br/#getting-started/configuring-controllers

Comment: Perfeito!. Desta forma, o administrador logado( ele utiliza a mesma tabela que a dos usuários comuns, só muda o campo role ), consegue criar um usuário, sem dar o erro de que já estou logado?

Comment: @Vinícius Não parei pra pensar nisso, acho que ele vai reclamar que já está logado. Você também pode sobreescrever o método create.

Comment: Dê uma olhada no código fonte do controlador: https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/app/controllers/devise/sessions_controller.rb Ali em cima tem um "require_no_authentication" para new e create. O jeito e ver se conseguimos eliminar isso.

Comment: Aí no caso, eu só pegava os parâmetros, e salvaria no banco? provavelmente o método create original, verifica se o current_user é nil, certo?

Comment: Eu creio que é isso que vc procura https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Manage-users-through-a-CRUD-interface

Comment: Nunca fiz isso antes, minha resposta é com base em pesquisa. Dê um olhada na dica do @Alex, ou tente adicionar `skip_before_action: :require_no_authentication` no controlador.

Comment: @user23970 Tentei utilizar o skip_before_action no meu controlador, e não consegui consertar este problema. O que eu poderia fazer?